# In Silverlight, how can a child control view model access the parent data context?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm, datacontext

**BACKGROUND:**
I have xaml similar to the following pseudo code

```
...
<DataContext><vm:parentVM/></DataContext>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
...
<local:myControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding vmChild}" />
```

**QUESTION:**
When I am processing some code in the context of the view model vmChild, how do I access properties and methods in the view model vmParent

Comment: is your vmChild a nested class inside of parentVM?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using MVVM and will be processing this code in a method handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: Assuming the Listbox's data context is in your childVM and the parent is a Grid which has its data context set from the ParentVM. Some casting trickery can allow you to access the goods.

```
  (((sender as ListBox).Parent as Grid).DataContext as ParentVM).VMProperty = "Cool";
```